# How to pass the item indexes in Observable.fromIterable to onNext in subscribe method?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to load the data and put it into a SparseArray using RxJava2. I get the data by calling an URL from an array, but I need the response parsed and inserted into the SparseArray with the order of the URL's in the array, so I need to pass the index of the String item in `mUrls.getGroups()`

Thanks in advance!

```
@GET
Single<ResponseBody> getChannels(@Url String url);


groups = new SparseArray<>();


Observable.fromIterable(mUrls.getGroups())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        //
        // How can I access the index of the String item in the array?
        //
        .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                Group group = GroupParser.parseList(responseBody.byteStream(), index);


                groups.put(index, group);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
 });
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the implemented solution:

```
 Observable.defer(() -> {
                        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
                        return Observable.fromIterable(mUrls.getGroups())
                                .map(url -> new Pair(url, counter.getAndIncrement()));
                    }).flatMapSingle(pair ->
                            aPI.getChannels(pair.first.toString())
                                    .map(responseBody -> new Pair(responseBody, pair.second))
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    )
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Pair>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Pair pair) {
                            Pair<ResponseBody, Integer> resultPair =  (Pair<ResponseBody, Integer>) pair;
                            Group group = GroupParser.parseList(resultPair.first.byteStream(),
                                    resultPair.second);

                            groups.put(resultPair.second, group);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "***** message: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "***** onComplete.");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the index of the String item in onNext method. Currently I can only access the responseBody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are processing the URLs sequentially, you can just introduce an `index` field in the `Observer`:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(mUrls.getGroups())
    .concatMapSingle(url -> getChannels(url))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {

         int index;  // <----------------------------------------------------

         // ...

         @Override
         public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {
             Group group = GroupParser.parseList(responseBody.byteStream(), index);


             groups.put(index, group);

             index++;  // <---------------------------------------------------------
         }

         // ...
    });
```

However, if you process the URLs concurrently, you have to pair up each URL with an index and tag it along. For example, given a `Pair` class:

```java
 Observable.defer(() -> {
     AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
     return Observable.fromIterable(mUrls.getGroups())
     .map(url -> Pair.of(url, counter.getAndIncremenet()));
 })
 .flatMapSingle(urlIndex -> 
     getChannels(urlIndex.first)
     .map(v -> Pair.of(v, urlIndex.second))
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 )
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Observer<Pair<ResponseBody, Integer>>() {

         // ...

         @Override
         public void onNext(Pair<ResponseBody, Integer> pair) {
             Group group = GroupParser.parseList(pair.first.byteStream(), pair.second);


             groups.put(pair.second, group);
         }

         // ...
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akarnokd. I will accept your answer after implementing it.

Comment: I implemented the second solution with a few modifications. The modified solution is added in the Edit section of the question. Thank you again.